# Select individual feature from ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am interested in using the `.sampleRegions` function to extract values from the following ImageCollection. In order to do this, I want to select the middle of the three images (index=1) contained within this image collection. Can anyone help me figure out how to select this image from the ImageCollection?

```
var MFR = ee.ImageCollection("LANDFIRE/Fire/MFRI/v1_2_0")
print(MFR)
```

output:

```
type: ImageCollection
id: LANDFIRE/Fire/MFRI/v1_2_0
version: 1633090983238815
bands: []
features: List (3 elements)
properties: Object (14 properties)
```

If I use `.first()`, I get the first image which has the desired form, but is the wrong image:

```
var MFR = ee.ImageCollection("LANDFIRE/Fire/MFRI/v1_2_0").first()
print(MFR)
```

output:

```
Image LANDFIRE/Fire/MFRI/v1_2_0/AK (1 band)
type: Image
id: LANDFIRE/Fire/MFRI/v1_2_0/AK
version: 1629985810765077
bands: List (1 element)
properties: Object (6 properties)
```

Is there an easy way to select the second image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the image id from your script, you can call the image by image id. As in the code below:

```js
var dataset = ee.Image('LANDFIRE/Fire/MFRI/v1_2_0/CONUS');
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! In this case, the first part of your answer `var dataset = ee.Image('LANDFIRE/Fire/MFRI/v1_2_0/CONUS');` is sufficient for what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have added those extra bit to visualize.